# How to jump to the end of pasted content after paste?

Tags: vim

For example, my current file conent is:

```
Hello world!
      ^------------------vim cursor here
```

Vim cursor is at character `w`。And I paste a word `foobar`，the content changed to `Hello Hello wfoobarorld`, and cursor is at character `f`. But I want the cursor jump to `r` of `foobar` after paste immediately. Is there some command to do that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

By default, the `p` and `P` commands should leave the cursor at the last character of the pasted text. `gp` and `gP` go one character forwards (first character after pasted text).

When you paste text, you have marks `[` and `]` set to the beginning and end of pasted text. Therefore you can use `` `[ `` and `` `] `` to move the cursor to begin/end of pasted content.

Comment: The first part about `p` and `P` is not true but +1 for the info on the auto marks placed on pasted text.

Comment: @JakeSellers The part about `p` and `P` are true for me when I test it in nvim and vim 8.1, unless I'm pasting an entire line.

Comment: @jdk1.0 well, it's true for special cases but not all.  That's Jake's point.  It's also not true for pasting paragraphs, which is the situation that is probably the most annoying to have the cursor-at-the-beginning behavior.