# How to move the cursor down to the text after you paste it in

Tags: vim

In most text applications, when you paste in text, the cursor ends up at the end of the text that has been pasted in. For example:

[image]

However, in vim the cursor doesn't move when you paste in text. Is it possible to advance to the end of the text after you paste it in (not knowing what the structure of the text might be when you add it? For example, it could be 1000 lines of text or just a word).

The current command I'm using to paste in is `"` `*` `p`

Answer (score 2):

> In most text applications, when you paste in text, the cursor ends up
>   at the end of the text that has been pasted in.

Vim does the same. But don't forget, "most text applications" they have only "INSERT"-like mode. If you entered INSERT mode of vim, and "paste" by `ctrl-r` + register, e.g. `ctrl-r "`. It works exactly the same as the "most text applications".

If you want `p/P` in normal mode to work like that too, you have to map the `p/P`. or using the 2nd step to `]/[` marks.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this answer to the same question a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767960/how-to-jump-to-the-end-of-pasted-content-after-paste), the paste commands `p`and `P` should automatically leave your cursor at the end of what you just pasted. If this is not the case for you, you can use the `[` and `]` marks to go to the beginning or end of the pasted text, like this:

- Go to the beginning: <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
- Go to the end: <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

The tick (`) is the command for moving to a named mark.

Answer (score -1):

Just use uppercase 'p', like this:

```
"*P
```

Here from the vim help:

```
["x]P       Put the text [from register x] before the cursor
            [count] times.
```

There is a trick you can use in insert mode to keep the indentation and place the cursor after your clipboard:

```
Ctrl-r Ctrl-o "Register"
```

In your case "primary selection" you can:

```
Ctrl-r Ctrl-o *
```

You can create a map for this

```
inoremap <S-Insert> <C-r><C-o>*
```